# Is there an R function to transform words in a cell to letters?

Tags: string, extract

I have DataFrame that looks like this

```
col1
"word1 word2 word3"
"word2 word3 word1"
```

And I am hoping to convert the sequence of words to a sequence of letters, like

```
col1
"abc"
"bca"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: need more information. Is the first row the template for the rest of the rows? it will always be abc?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used R. Use the below(JavaScript) as pseudo code to do what you need in R.
Based on the limited data. This is what I have. If it does not help, it may give you hints into what you need to do.

[Loopy Rewrite for Data:jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzt61cs2/1/)

- Loop through the array
- Compare elements
- write out new value based on default row

  ```
    let data = [
        "word1 word2 word3",
        "word1 word3 word2",
        "word2 word3 word1",
        "word2 word1 word3",
        "word3 word2 word1",
        "word3 word1 word2"
    ];

    let newData = []
    let defaultRow;
    // act on each row to determine order
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
        // if first row it is our template for ordering
        if (index === 0) {
            defaultRow = row.split(' ');
            // can be more dynamic here about what is used and if more words in row
            newData.push("abc");
        } else {
            let result = '';
            // take your string and for each row and turn into an array
            row.split(' ').forEach((word) => {
                let index = defaultRow.indexOf(word);
                // assuming always three words this should work
                if (index >= 0 && index < 3) {
                    // concatenate value to end of string
                    result += index === 0 ? 'a' : index === 1 ? 'b' : 'c';
                } else {
                    console.log('bad data');
                }
            })
            newData.push(result);
        }
    });
    alert(newData);
  ```